# How to use ajax with Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Guys i have made a blog using Laravel framework, today I just heard about ajax, What I heard is in short: it loads data quickly. My issue is that I have many routes , controllers with views.

What steps do i need to use so called ajax javascript?

```
  <script>

   $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') 
  }
  });

  jQuery.ajax({
    url:'/blog',
    type: 'GET',

    success: getIndex(  ){

        console.log( );
      },

  });

 </script>
```

Comment: I am a beginner, first step to website world, and framework

Comment: This is a place where you get help with your code and problems. Not a guide or tutorial site. You'll find better resources by searching online.

Comment: I dont think so its all about code @sandeesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically the same, when you make a HTTP request using ajax, you need to define the route you are requesting, for example this ajax request:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'your/url',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
```

You define your route like a normal route would be, since this ajax request is type "post", you define your route as "post":

```
Route::post('your/url', 'yourController@yourFunctionInsideController')->name('your.route.alias');
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance,  i will give it a try today

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can be used normally in Laravel, I particularly usually host my codes in `'/ public / js'` and then extend through the `<script>` so that the code is not mixed. I advise you to study Laravel's structure, read the documentation, see some videos. Your question is very broad, so I will leave some materials that are of interest to you.

Book by Novatec about Ajax:

https://www.novatec.com.br/livros/ajaxjquery/

Laravel Docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/